# window.open() not playing well with anchors in Firefox 3

Tags: firefox, anchor, mozilla, window.open

The following javascript, intended to open a new window ***and*** jump to a specified anchor, works great in IE. Unfortunately, in Firefox, it opens the window, but it doesn't jump to the anchor.

I've been struggling with this problem for a couple of days now (searches and modifications) to no avail.

If anybody has any insight as to how I can get this to work as intended in both IE ***and*** Mozilla browsers, I'd be forever grateful.

Here's the javascript function containing window.open() and the link calling the function containing window.open():

```
<html>
<head>
<script language=javascript>
function openPopupWindow_Why(sPopupUrl, sPopupLabel)
{
    window.open(sPopupUrl, sPopupLabel, 'toolbar=no,resizable=yes,
         scrollbars=yes,height=250,width=450', false);
    return false;
}
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<A onclick="openPopupWindow_Why('MyProfile_WhyAsk.htm#ethnicity', 'Why')"
     href="javascript:void(0)" class="WhyAsk">Why do we ask?</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the HTML anchor on the page that's opened by window.open():

```
<tr>
  <td align="center">
    <a name="#ethnicity">&nbsp;</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the # from the ethnicity anchor name like so:

```
<tr>
  <td align="center">
    <a name="ethnicity">&nbsp;</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Works in at least IE, Firefox and Chrome

Comment: You fixed it Gordon. Much obliged!